# Vetur marks first line of .vue file as an error

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

My vscode vetur plugin is marking the first line of vue files as an error. This is the code using a completely blank .vue file template

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    
  }
</script>
<style scoped>
    
</style>
```

However the <template> line is marked as an error. Here is the error message:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => any'.
  Type '{}' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): any'. Vetur(2345) [1,1]
```

I have confirmed that vetur is the only plugin doing anything on .vue files by disabling all other plugins

My vscode info is here:

```
Version: 1.47.2
Commit: 17299e413d5590b14ab0340ea477cdd86ff13daf
Date: 2020-07-15T18:22:15.161Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-42-generic
```

And I am using Vetur 0.25.0

I am completely stumped on what could be causing this. Not having intellisense and code completion due to this is driving me crazy

Comment: just add an empty `<div></div>` inside template and that error won't come anymore.

Comment: @brandon I can't reproduce that error with the SFC you've described. I see an ESLint error `The template root requires exactly one element`. What versions of VS Code and Vetur are you using? Are you using a Vue CLI generated project?

Comment: For some reason this is only an issue on my vscode. The people I am working with on this project aren't experiencing any issues. 
I tried adding a <div></div> inside the template and the error still persists
This is my vscode version
Version: 1.47.2
Commit: 17299e413d5590b14ab0340ea477cdd86ff13daf
Date: 2020-07-15T18:22:15.161Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-42-generic

And as for Vetur i am using 0.25.0

Comment: Getting same issue if anyone has a fix

Answer (score 3):

Disable experimantal template interpolation in veutr extenssion settings,

`"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": false`

Answer (score 0):

I did not spent time to figure out the root cause, but removing the .vscode folder solved it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, as you can see in this GitHub thread:
[Vetur- Template interpolation error...](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1305)

You can try one of the workarounds proposed there:
[alukos commented on 27 Sep 2019](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1305#issuecomment-535979694)

Or you can try to change Vetur config via settings or via [vetur.config.js file](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/reference/)
setting templateInterpolationService to false as @Jaideep Heer said.

```
"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": false
```

Restart editor to take full effect, and the error should disappear.

Regards.